# How to make a div responsive in height/width with text as the same sizes of a div with an image?

Tags: jquery, css

I have a grid:

```
<div class="img"><img src="#" /></div>
<div class="img"><img src="#" /></div>
<div class="quote"><p>Lorem ipsum</p></div>
<div class="img"><img src="#" /></div>
<div class="quote"><p>Lorem ipsum</p></div>
<div class="img"><img src="#" /></div>
```

CSS

```
div {
   width: 25%;
}

.img {
   display: block;
   max-width: 100%;
   height: auto;
   width: 100%;
}

.quote {
   ?
}
```

In jQuery i'd do:

```
var imgHeight = $(".img").height();
$(".quote").height(imgHeight);
```

I thought of using a fake img for `.quote` or I wonder if i should go jQuery to calculate `.img` div sizes and apply them to `.quote`. Is it there any other css approach that'll do it?

Comment: Check out Flexbox, it might just be the solution for you if I understand your question correctly. In Flexbox, you can tell through CSS that a div has to be the same height as another div.

Comment: @Rvervuurt awesome, didn't know about flexbox layout module. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 2 solutions:

jQuery

```
var imgHeight = $(".img").height();
$(".quote").height(imgHeight);
```

CSS3

[FlexBox layout module](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-flexbox/)